# What are the differences in code execution between Console App and Windows Service

Tags: c#, usb

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DisableDevice;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Management;

namespace DisableDevice
{

    [Flags()]
    internal enum SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags
    {
        Default = 1,
        Present = 2,
        AllClasses = 4,
        Profile = 8,
        DeviceInterface = (int)0x10
    }

    internal enum DiFunction
    {
        SelectDevice = 1,
        InstallDevice = 2,
        AssignResources = 3,
        Properties = 4,
        Remove = 5,
        FirstTimeSetup = 6,
        FoundDevice = 7,
        SelectClassDrivers = 8,
        ValidateClassDrivers = 9,
        InstallClassDrivers = (int)0xa,
        CalcDiskSpace = (int)0xb,
        DestroyPrivateData = (int)0xc,
        ValidateDriver = (int)0xd,
        Detect = (int)0xf,
        InstallWizard = (int)0x10,
        DestroyWizardData = (int)0x11,
        PropertyChange = (int)0x12,
        EnableClass = (int)0x13,
        DetectVerify = (int)0x14,
        InstallDeviceFiles = (int)0x15,
        UnRemove = (int)0x16,
        SelectBestCompatDrv = (int)0x17,
        AllowInstall = (int)0x18,
        RegisterDevice = (int)0x19,
        NewDeviceWizardPreSelect = (int)0x1a,
        NewDeviceWizardSelect = (int)0x1b,
        NewDeviceWizardPreAnalyze = (int)0x1c,
        NewDeviceWizardPostAnalyze = (int)0x1d,
        NewDeviceWizardFinishInstall = (int)0x1e,
        Unused1 = (int)0x1f,
        InstallInterfaces = (int)0x20,
        DetectCancel = (int)0x21,
        RegisterCoInstallers = (int)0x22,
        AddPropertyPageAdvanced = (int)0x23,
        AddPropertyPageBasic = (int)0x24,
        Reserved1 = (int)0x25,
        Troubleshooter = (int)0x26,
        PowerMessageWake = (int)0x27,
        AddRemotePropertyPageAdvanced = (int)0x28,
        UpdateDriverUI = (int)0x29,
        Reserved2 = (int)0x30
    }

    internal enum StateChangeAction
    {
        Enable = 1,
        Disable = 2,
        PropChange = 3,
        Start = 4,
        Stop = 5
    }

    [Flags()]
    internal enum Scopes
    {
        Global = 1,
        ConfigSpecific = 2,
        ConfigGeneral = 4
    }

    internal enum SetupApiError
    {
        NoAssociatedClass = unchecked((int)0xe0000200),
        ClassMismatch = unchecked((int)0xe0000201),
        DuplicateFound = unchecked((int)0xe0000202),
        NoDriverSelected = unchecked((int)0xe0000203),
        KeyDoesNotExist = unchecked((int)0xe0000204),
        InvalidDevinstName = unchecked((int)0xe0000205),
        InvalidClass = unchecked((int)0xe0000206),
        DevinstAlreadyExists = unchecked((int)0xe0000207),
        DevinfoNotRegistered = unchecked((int)0xe0000208),
        InvalidRegProperty = unchecked((int)0xe0000209),
        NoInf = unchecked((int)0xe000020a),
        NoSuchHDevinst = unchecked((int)0xe000020b),
        CantLoadClassIcon = unchecked((int)0xe000020c),
        InvalidClassInstaller = unchecked((int)0xe000020d),
        DiDoDefault = unchecked((int)0xe000020e),
        DiNoFileCopy = unchecked((int)0xe000020f),
        InvalidHwProfile = unchecked((int)0xe0000210),
        NoDeviceSelected = unchecked((int)0xe0000211),
        DevinfolistLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000212),
        DevinfodataLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000213),
        DiBadPath = unchecked((int)0xe0000214),
        NoClassInstallParams = unchecked((int)0xe0000215),
        FileQueueLocked = unchecked((int)0xe0000216),
        BadServiceInstallSect = unchecked((int)0xe0000217),
        NoClassDriverList = unchecked((int)0xe0000218),
        NoAssociatedService = unchecked((int)0xe0000219),
        NoDefaultDeviceInterface = unchecked((int)0xe000021a),
        DeviceInterfaceActive = unchecked((int)0xe000021b),
        DeviceInterfaceRemoved = unchecked((int)0xe000021c),
        BadInterfaceInstallSect = unchecked((int)0xe000021d),
        NoSuchInterfaceClass = unchecked((int)0xe000021e),
        InvalidReferenceString = unchecked((int)0xe000021f),
        InvalidMachineName = unchecked((int)0xe0000220),
        RemoteCommFailure = unchecked((int)0xe0000221),
        MachineUnavailable = unchecked((int)0xe0000222),
        NoConfigMgrServices = unchecked((int)0xe0000223),
        InvalidPropPageProvider = unchecked((int)0xe0000224),
        NoSuchDeviceInterface = unchecked((int)0xe0000225),
        DiPostProcessingRequired = unchecked((int)0xe0000226),
        InvalidCOInstaller = unchecked((int)0xe0000227),
        NoCompatDrivers = unchecked((int)0xe0000228),
        NoDeviceIcon = unchecked((int)0xe0000229),
        InvalidInfLogConfig = unchecked((int)0xe000022a),
        DiDontInstall = unchecked((int)0xe000022b),
        InvalidFilterDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022c),
        NonWindowsNTDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022d),
        NonWindowsDriver = unchecked((int)0xe000022e),
        NoCatalogForOemInf = unchecked((int)0xe000022f),
        DevInstallQueueNonNative = unchecked((int)0xe0000230),
        NotDisableable = unchecked((int)0xe0000231),
        CantRemoveDevinst = unchecked((int)0xe0000232),
        InvalidTarget = unchecked((int)0xe0000233),
        DriverNonNative = unchecked((int)0xe0000234),
        InWow64 = unchecked((int)0xe0000235),
        SetSystemRestorePoint = unchecked((int)0xe0000236),
        IncorrectlyCopiedInf = unchecked((int)0xe0000237),
        SceDisabled = unchecked((int)0xe0000238),
        UnknownException = unchecked((int)0xe0000239),
        PnpRegistryError = unchecked((int)0xe000023a),
        RemoteRequestUnsupported = unchecked((int)0xe000023b),
        NotAnInstalledOemInf = unchecked((int)0xe000023c),
        InfInUseByDevices = unchecked((int)0xe000023d),
        DiFunctionObsolete = unchecked((int)0xe000023e),
        NoAuthenticodeCatalog = unchecked((int)0xe000023f),
        AuthenticodeDisallowed = unchecked((int)0xe0000240),
        AuthenticodeTrustedPublisher = unchecked((int)0xe0000241),
        AuthenticodeTrustNotEstablished = unchecked((int)0xe0000242),
        AuthenticodePublisherNotTrusted = unchecked((int)0xe0000243),
        SignatureOSAttributeMismatch = unchecked((int)0xe0000244),
        OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode = unchecked((int)0xe0000245)
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DeviceInfoData
    {
        public int Size;
        public Guid ClassGuid;
        public int DevInst;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct PropertyChangeParameters
    {
        public int Size;
        // part of header. It's flattened out into 1 structure.
        public DiFunction DiFunction;
        public StateChangeAction StateChange;
        public Scopes Scope;
        public int HwProfile;
    }

    internal class NativeMethods
    {

        private const string setupapi = "setupapi.dll";

        private NativeMethods()
        {
        }

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction installFunction, SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, int memberIndex, ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle SetupDiGetClassDevs([In()]
ref Guid classGuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
string enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags flags);

        /*
        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData did, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
StringBuilder deviceInstanceId, int deviceInstanceIdSize, [Out()]
ref int requiredSize);
        */
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
           IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
           ref DeviceInfoData did,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder DeviceInstanceId,
           int DeviceInstanceIdSize,
           out int RequiredSize
        );

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr deviceInfoSet);

        [DllImport(setupapi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle deviceInfoSet, [In()]
ref DeviceInfoData deviceInfoData, [In()]
ref PropertyChangeParameters classInstallParams, int classInstallParamsSize);

    }

    internal class SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {

        public SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return NativeMethods.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(this.handle);
        }

    }

    public sealed class DeviceHelper
    {

        private DeviceHelper()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enable or disable a device.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="classGuid">The class guid of the device. Available in the device manager.</param>
        /// <param name="instanceId">The device instance id of the device. Available in the device manager.</param>
        /// <param name="enable">True to enable, False to disable.</param>
        /// <remarks>Will throw an exception if the device is not Disableable.</remarks>
        public static void SetDeviceEnabled(Guid classGuid, string instanceId, bool enable)
        {
            SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle diSetHandle = null;
            try
            {
                // Get the handle to a device information set for all devices matching classGuid that are present on the 
                // system.
                diSetHandle = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, null, IntPtr.Zero, SetupDiGetClassDevsFlags.Present);
                // Get the device information data for each matching device.
                DeviceInfoData[] diData = GetDeviceInfoData(diSetHandle);
                // Find the index of our instance. i.e. the touchpad mouse - I have 3 mice attached...
                int index = GetIndexOfInstance(diSetHandle, diData, instanceId);
                // Disable...
                EnableDevice(diSetHandle, diData[index], enable);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (diSetHandle != null)
                {
                    if (diSetHandle.IsClosed == false)
                    {
                        diSetHandle.Close();
                    }
                    diSetHandle.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private static DeviceInfoData[] GetDeviceInfoData(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle)
        {
            List<DeviceInfoData> data = new List<DeviceInfoData>();
            DeviceInfoData did = new DeviceInfoData();
            int didSize = Marshal.SizeOf(did);
            did.Size = didSize;
            int index = 0;
            while (NativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(handle, index, ref did))
            {
                data.Add(did);
                index += 1;
                did = new DeviceInfoData();
                did.Size = didSize;
            }
            return data.ToArray();
        }

        // Find the index of the particular DeviceInfoData for the instanceId.
        private static int GetIndexOfInstance(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle, DeviceInfoData[] diData, string instanceId)
        {
            const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
            for (int index = 0; index <= diData.Length - 1; index++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1);
                int requiredSize = 0;
                bool result = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref diData[index], sb, sb.Capacity, out requiredSize);
                if (result == false && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                {
                    sb.Capacity = requiredSize;
                    result = NativeMethods.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), ref diData[index], sb, sb.Capacity, out requiredSize);
                }
                if (result == false)
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                if (instanceId.Equals(sb.ToString()))
                {
                    return index;
                }
            }
            // not found
            return -1;
        }

        // enable/disable...
        private static void EnableDevice(SafeDeviceInfoSetHandle handle, DeviceInfoData diData, bool enable)
        {
            PropertyChangeParameters @params = new PropertyChangeParameters();
            // The size is just the size of the header, but we've flattened the structure.
            // The header comprises the first two fields, both integer.
            @params.Size = 8;
            @params.DiFunction = DiFunction.PropertyChange;
            @params.Scope = Scopes.Global;
            if (enable)
            {
                @params.StateChange = StateChangeAction.Enable;
            }
            else
            {
                @params.StateChange = StateChangeAction.Disable;
            }

            bool result = NativeMethods.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(handle, ref diData, ref @params, Marshal.SizeOf(@params));
            if (result == false) throw new Win32Exception();
            result = NativeMethods.SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DiFunction.PropertyChange, handle, ref diData);
            if (result == false)
            {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (err == (int)SetupApiError.NotDisableable)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Device can't be disabled (programmatically or in Device Manager).");
                else if (err >= (int)SetupApiError.NoAssociatedClass && err <= (int)SetupApiError.OnlyValidateViaAuthenticode)
                    throw new Win32Exception("SetupAPI error: " + ((SetupApiError)err).ToString());
                else
                    throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 applications that use this helper: a simple test application Console App and a working project WindowsService(running under the user LocalSystem).
In ConsoleApp everything works without errors, but here when it is executed in Windows Service there is an error in

```
NativeMethods.SetupDiCallClassInstaller with the code "13".
```

I can't understand why a simple application does this and a working project doesn't.Thank you in advance.

I wanted to achieve the restriction of interaction with usb-stick. WindowsService should regulate access to flash drives, should be installed on all computers in the company and for some users to prohibit the use of flash drives, and to allow someone.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, really but my first attempt would be to look for a setting in AD Group Policy or something alike. I am somewhat confident that it should be possible to use AD settings for this. But since I am not an Admin I am not sure if it's possible and I cannot give further advice, I am afraid.

Comment: As stated in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdicallclassinstaller), the caller must be in the Administrators group for certain calls. Is your return code 13d or 13h?

Comment: I found this Q&A on Servervault: [Restrict access to certain USB drives](https://serverfault.com/q/368812) , hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred because there was a FileSystemWatcher subscription that I was not aware of. I found this because I created a new project and gradually moved the code from the old project to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand why a simple application does this and a working
>   project doesn't.Thank you in advance.

Its actually very easy to understand. A console application is not a service, though they might seem like they are the same, they have some very sharp (and also very subtle) differences. Way to many for this answer

So where do we go from here?

You are doing a great job of getting the error code, but whats the error? what does it mean, you need to figure this out. I suggest using

```
string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
```

At least this will allow you to see whats going on.

Also a previous pointed out in the documentation [`SetupDiCallClassInstaller function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx)

> Note  For certain DIF requests, the caller must be a member of the
>   Administrators group. For such DIF requests, this requirement is
>   listed on the reference page for the associated default handler.

However my suspicious its not actually the `SetupDiCallClassInstaller` call thats going wrong assuming your error code is actually `(int)13` and you are probably feeding it an invalid handle or something  (just a guess)

**The error code 13**

[Win32 Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx)

> ERROR_INVALID_DATA
>
> 13 (0xD)
>
> The data is invalid.

All i can suggest is using better logging, read the documentaiton for each method, get better error descriptions, and more defensive coding to understand the nature of your problem

Comment: If I'm sending data incorrectly, then why is the console application working correctly? The data is sent to both applications the same.

Comment: @OlegStepanov I give you no explanation what is wrong with the chain of calls you make, all i am trying to do is point you in a direction where you can figure this out. The error (if correct) would be pointing to the usage of the function and not to the specifics of what you are trying to achieve. Obviously there is something different between the console, and service, permissions, privileges. if you are more defensive with the results from each call and check for problems, you will be able to deduce why its not working